# How to create layout with edit text dynamically added and removed at run time

Tags: java, android

I am working on a survey application and I need to know how to create a layout that lets the user enter multiple answers for a question, once he types in the first text then the next one should be generated dynamically below the first one.

Also, how can I make the edit texts removable?

Like this layout :   [image]

Comment: You probably have to use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` because the views numbers are not defined which can create memory problems if gets more in numbrs/

Answer (score 3):

This code will help you

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Edit Text" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button buttonView;
    private LinearLayout parentLayout;
    private int hint=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
        parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createEditTextView();
            }
        });
    }
    protected void createEditTextView() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        params.setMargins(0,10,0,10);
        EditText edittTxt = new EditText(this);
        int maxLength = 5;
        hint++;
        edittTxt.setHint("editText"+hint);
        edittTxt.setLayoutParams(params);
        // edtTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        edittTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        edittTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
        edittTxt.setId(hint);
        InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
        fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        edittTxt.setFilters(fArray);
        parentLayout.addView(edittTxt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a new **EditText(View)** and add it to your **layout** at the prefered position.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutDecisions);

EditText editText = new EditText(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

editText.setLayoutParams(p);

linearLayout.addView(editText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TableLayout and TableRow. You can add and remove dynamically very easily.

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) could be a good starting point